# How to get HTTPS working with apache on linux

Tags: apache, https

I have installed apache2 on ubuntu 18.04 and created a simple website that can be reached (after I did port forwarding for port 80) with http://IP_NUMBER.

Next, I wanted to get it working with https, and therefore followed the instructions in both links below:

https://hostadvice.com/how-to/configure-apache-with-tls-ssl-certificate-on-ubuntu-18/

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-18-04

However, I did not get it to work. In both cases i just got the Unable To Connect-message from firefox. Please help me with how I can proceed, what can be wrong and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.
I needed to do port port forwarding for port 443.
The did not mention that in any of the two links above.